# PHP (XML source) to HTML

Tags: php, html, xml, output

I have got an XML source in .php so I would like to Convert the xml "strings" to a HTML file.
The PHP file shows this:

```
<root>
     <servers>
          <realm>
               <id>2</id>                       #Sever ID
               <name>UNN</name>                 #Sever Name
               <ip>**.***.**.**</ip>            #Server IP
               <port>1020</port>                #Server Port
               <online>2</online>               #Online players
               <status>Offline</status>         #Server Status
               <limit>50</limit>                #Server Max Player Limit
               <wg_owner>0</wg_owner>           #"If" 0 string = 'A', "Else" string = 'B'
               <wg_inwartime>0</wg_inwartime>   #"If 0 string = 'Yes', Else string = 'No'
               <wg_timer>7879654</wg_timer>     #Just a timer
          </realm>
     </servers>
</root>
```

So This is what I would like to write into a HTML file (The xml file is dynamically refreshing!)

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn basic XSLT to convert XML into HTML parsable text

Comment: just google "parse xml php" and you'll find your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions, incliding `DOMDocument`. Look into `DOMDocument::importNode` at:

http://php.net/domdocument.importnode

Example 1 might show you what you need to know.